# Print Fibonacci sequence up to nth place?

Tags: java

I am trying to print the entire fibonacci sequence up to a given place. So the user would decide how many numbers of the fibonacci sequence they want to see (up to 16 repetitions) and it would print the entire sequence.

My current code only prints the number in the sequences for the place that you choose.
ex: 4 prints 2 instead of 0 1 1 2.

```
public int Fibonacci(int number){
    if(number == 1 || number == 2){
        return 1;
    }
    int fib1=1, fib2=1, fibonacci=1;
    for(int count= 3; count<= number; count++){
        fibonacci = fib1 + fib2;
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = fibonacci;
    }
    return fibonacci;
}
```

Here is my main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FibonacciPrinter 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int input = in.nextInt();

        FibonacciGenerator newNumber = new FibonacciGenerator();

        for(int fibCount = 0; fibCount < input; fibCount++)
        {
            System.out.println(newNumber.Fibonacci(input));
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here,

```
for(int fibCount = 0; fibCount < input; fibCount++)
{
  System.out.println(newNumber.Fibonacci(input));
}
```

You almost certainly wanted,

```
for(int fibCount = 0; fibCount < input; fibCount++)
{
  System.out.println(newNumber.Fibonacci(fibCount)); // <-- fibCount not input
}
```

You need to update your method to handle the zero case, for example

```
 public int Fibonacci(int number) {
   if (number == 0) return 0;
   // ...
 }
```

and in Java, the convention would name `Fibonacci` to `fibonacci` because method names are camel case starting with a lower case letter (classes start with a capital letter by convention).

Comment: That worked great. Now I just have the problem of all the numbers running together. I think I need to convert it to a string I'm just not positive how to do that? I might need to ask a separate question after I mess with this some more.